# Неверная работа с AutoCompieteTextview

Tags: java, android

Делаю функцию поиска в приложении. Алгоритм такой: пользователь вводит текст(ищет логин) в поле, затем делается запрос на сайт, после чего выпадают похожие логины. Очень похоже на то, как поисковик показывает фразы. Использую такой код:

```
String answer = "";
String[] Dialogs;
int login_length = 0;
String login;
String password;

AutoCompleteTextView mAutoComplete;
String[] Find_Logins = new String[3];


@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                              int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(s.toString().length() > 3) {
        //mAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Find_Logins));

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("find_login", s.toString())
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://s92640jz.bget.ru/find_login.php")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        client.newCall(request)
                .enqueue(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(final Call call, IOException e) {
                        // Error
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка при отправке запроса, проверьте подключение к сети", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                toast.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                        String res = response.body().string();
                        Log.d("TAG123", "All response is: " + res);

                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(res);
                            int count = jsonObject.length();
                            if (count == 3) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < Find_Logins.length; i++) {

                                    Find_Logins[i] = jsonObject.getString("find_login" + Integer.toString(i));
                                    //Log.d("TAG123", "Dialog: " + answer);
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                                    Find_Logins[i] = jsonObject.getString("find_login" + Integer.toString(i));
                                    //Log.d("TAG123", "Dialog: " + answer);
                                }
                            }

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mAutoComplete.addTextChangedListener(dialogs.this);
                                    mAutoComplete.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(dialogs.this,
                                            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Find_Logins));
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        catch (JSONException e){}
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

По логике всё вроде должно работать ни ничего не "выпадает" при вводе информации. Третий день уже бьюсь.

Comment: поработайте под отладчиком, так вы сможете определить,  в чем проблема

Comment: у вас в странном месте TextChangeListener добавляется... он должен быть в onCreateView (или onActivityCreated и т.д.) и никак не в том месте где он сейчас указан. может быть вы его просто не назначили...